# Apply SVN patch in reverse or undo patch

Tags: svn

I modified some files with `svn patch <my-patch-file>`.
How do I reverse this patch without reverting other changes in these files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run `svn patch --reverse-diff <my-patch-file>`. [Source](http://svnbook.redbean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.reverse_diff)